# Building a primary links bar

Tags: html, css

What I want: building a simple links/navigation bar.

What I have in my css:

```
.ico    {
    width:40px;
}
```

What I have in my html:

```
<body>
 <div id="logo">
 <img src="logo.png" id="test" />
 <img class="ico" src="images/home.png" />
 <img class="ico" src="images/calendar.png" />
 <img class="ico" src="images/support.png" />
 <img class="ico" src="images/globe.png" />
 <img class="ico" src="images/email.png" />
 <div style="width:auto; border-style:solid; border-width:0px 0px 3px; border-color:#202020;"></div>
 </div>
 <div id="main">
 <h1 class="title">This is the main title</h1>
 <p>This is a sample paragraph.</p>
 </div></body>
```

How it looks like:
[image]

What is required: The images (home, calendar, support, globe, email) need to be equally spaced and be distributed from the start of the logo (DAERA) to the end of the screen, for all screen resolutions and devices.

Comment: You can use bootstrap grid. Here is a reference link, [bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/examples/grid/).

Comment: You will have to use @media querie for the resolutions you want and I would use ul and li... set ul as display:table; and li display:table-cell more flexible than table alone

Comment: tables are a big no-no. otherwise I could have simply done it all with a bit of table tweaking and aligning the data in the center of the table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be helpful for you. Your HTML markup:

```
<div class="box">
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>​
```

Your CSS:

```
.box{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

Comment: Superb! But ... it is aligning all the images to the top side of the div. I need them to be aligned on the bottom side. So. What now?

Answer (score 0):

```
.ico {
    width:40px;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Could you please add some explanation to your answer? Code-only answers are frowned upon on SO.

Comment: This does not _evenly_ distribute all the icons on the screen to the end of the page :S